# Why is marginTop being calculated from a different reference point on a desktop web browser than on my mobile device browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The top photo is a screenshot from USB debug mode with my Pixel 6XL connected to laptop. The checkered area is the URL bar in the chrome browser on my Pixel.

The bottom screen shot is from my actual laptop web browser (chrome).

The app bar at the top is transparent for debugging purposes. I have marginTop=64px of the component which contains the list of messages, which is the height of the AppBar (I want the list component to start at the bottom of the AppBar component). On my mobile device, it appears to be calculating the marginTop from the top of the device screen rather than the top of the browser viewport. If I set marginTop = 0px, then the content in the list is pushed into the checkered area (browser URL Bar). On my laptop web browser, the behavior appears to be different/correct, where it's calculating marginTop from the bottom of the browser URL bar.

The strange thing is that this worked for me before, and I can't figure out what has changed.

I also checked on Firefox on my mobile device, and it has the same problem so it doesn't appear to be specific to Chrome.

I'm new to JS/react, so I'm not exactly sure which context is most helpful to troubleshoot this without copying in entire file contents here.

tldr; component behavior is different on mobile browser than on laptop browser.

Here's the only css files I have:

index.css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #282c34;
,
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

App.css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}
```

And here's the component code:

```
 <Box
      className="ChatFormView_parent"
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
       // flexGrow: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        // height: `${viewportHeight}px`,
        height: '100vh',
       // marginTop: "164px",
      }}
    >
      <Box
        className="ChatMessageListView_parent"
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          overflowY: "auto",
          width: "100%",
          maxWidth: "md",
          marginTop: '64px',
          bgcolor: '#444654',
          borderRadius: 2,

          "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
            width: "2px",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
          },
          "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
            borderRadius: "3px",
            backgroundColor: "#aaa",
          },
          "&::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
            borderRadius: "3px",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
          },
        }}
      >
        <ChatMessageListView messages={messages} />
      </Box>
      <Box
        className="TextFieldView_parent"
        sx={{
          position: "sticky",
          bottom: 0,
          zIndex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          paddingBottom: "15px",
          paddingTop: "15px",
          width: "100%",
          maxWidth: "md",
          margin: "0 auto",
        }}
      >
        <TextFieldView onSubmit={handleTextSubmit} />
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Margins can do some very strange (or at least, surprising) things. What is above the box with the margin that is not working? Do any style rules do things differently because of CSS media queries on the smaller screen? Have you tried it in your browser using the debugger tools to make the desktop browser look/act more like a mobile browser?

Comment: I've added some more context to the post - the CSS I have plus the component code that I'm having issues with (though I admit I have no idea if it's related to any of the parent components that it's wrapped in). The component above the box with the margin that's not working is the AppBar, which is fixed to the top of the screen and has a fixed height of 64px (regardless of screen size/device).

Comment: This is interesting - when I install and run it as an app on my mobile device (no URL bar), the behavior works as desired.

Comment: However, I still need this to render correctly when it's viewed in a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the issue was I was setting the height of a parent component to '100vh'. I still don't fully understand why this created the strange behavior on the mobile device, other than the fact that mobile and desktop browsers treat the vh property differently apparently.